# How do I post/upload multiple files at once using HttpClient?

Tags: ruby, httpclient

```
def test_post_with_file filename = 'test01.xml'
    File.open(filename) do |file|
        response = @http_client.post(url, {'documents'=>file})
    end
end
```

How do I modify the above method to handle a multi-file-array post/upload?

```
file_array = ['test01.xml', 'test02.xml']
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
def test_post_with_file(file_array=[])
  file_array.each do |filename|
    File.open(filename) do |file|
      response = @http_client.post(url, {'documents'=>file})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks tiger.  While I know for a fact your solution would work, I was looking for a way to test the upload of multiple files in 1 http_client.post (the way you have it now,  you're just looping through the number of array count ; multiple http_client.post)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and finally figured out how to do it:

```
def test_post_with_file(file_array)
  form = file_array.map { |n| ['documents[]', File.open(n)] }
  response = @http_client.post(@url, form)
end
```

You can see in the docs how to pass multiple values: http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTPClient#post_content-instance_method .

In the "body" row, I tried without success to use the 4th example. Somehow HttpClient just decides to apply `.to_s` to each hash in the array.

Then I tried the 2nd solution and it wouldn't work either because only the last value is kept by the server. But I discovered after some tinkering that the second solution works if the parameter name includes the square brackets to indicate there are mutiple values as an array.

Maybe this is a bug in Sinatra (that's what I'm using), maybe the handling of such data is implementation-dependent, maybe the HttpClient doc is outdated/wrong. Or a combination of these.